# Measuring compaign for mobile app

Tags: android, google-analytics, sdk

I am trying to measure campaigns and traffics sources when deep linking to a mobile app, and I am following this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/mobile-campaign-deep-link.

I have enabled deep links for my app content by adding the intent filters:

```
  <application
    android:name="com.package.DeepLinkingapp.Myapp"
    android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.package.DeepLinkingapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <!-- this makes it available to the launcher -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- this makes it openable with browser -->
        <!-- Accept chrome links -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="myscheme"
                android:host="deeplinking"
                android:pathPrefix="/"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Accept adb data flag -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="myscheme"
                android:host="deeplinking" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.package.DeepLinkingapp.LoginDisplayActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login_display" />

</application>
```

After that, I have tagged an URL like this:

```
myscheme://deeplinking?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=monsite&utm_campaign=apps
```

Finally, I've sent data to GA by using the *setCampaignParamsFromUrl* method in *onCreate* method:

```
Tracker tracker = ((Myapp) getApplication()).getTracker(Myapp.TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER);
    tracker.setScreenName("Page d'identification"); // définir la page

    Intent test = this.getIntent();
    Uri data = test.getData();
    if (data == null) {System.out.println("no URI found");}
    else{
        System.out.println("URI = " + data);
        String campaignData = data.getEncodedPath();
    tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().setCampaignParamsFromUrl(campaignData).build());
    }

    tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

The problem is that I have no data in the interface GA about this campaign, I should precise that I’ve done the test in this page: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns. And it works but only for the source:

[image: Screen shot]

Did you know why I have nothing about my campaign in Ga? Did I skip some steps?

Thank you very much.